# Extended double 2-cocycle conditions: Mathematical structure behind?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology

> Note: For experts, to save your time, you can just read the highlighted texts and Eqs directly.

1. The ordinary group 2-cocycle condition:

Let us remind the usual so-called homogeneous group 2-cocycle $\mu(a,b,c)$ of cohomology group $H^2(G,U(1))$ where $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is given by

> $$
> \frac{\mu(b,c,d)\mu(a,b,d)}{\mu(a,c,d)\mu(a,b,c)}=1.
> $$
>   where all $a,b,c,d \in G$.

- We can focus on the case $G$ is a finite group (or even finite Abelian group if you want to simplify further.)

See References on group cohomogy:

- [Dijkgraaf-Witten (1990)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104180750)
- [Wang-Gu-Wen (2014)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.031601) [Appendices on cocycle conditions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7689.pdf)

The homogeneous group 2-cocycle $\mu(a,b,c)$ can be coverted to a homogeneous group 2-cocycle via
$$
\omega(A,B):=\omega(a d^{-1},b d^{-1})= \mu(a d^{-1},b d^{-1},1).
$$
so if we define $a d^{-1}=A$ and $b d^{-1}=B$, $c d^{-1}=C$, then

$$
\frac{\mu(bd^{-1},cd^{-1},1)\mu(ad^{-1} , b  d^{-1},1)}{\mu(a  d^{-1},c d^{-1},1)\mu(a c^{-1},b c^{-1},1)}=\frac{\mu(B,C,1)\mu(A , B,1)}{\mu(A,C,1)\mu(AC^{-1}, BC^{-1},1)}=
\frac{\omega(B,C)\omega(A,B)}{\omega(A,C)\omega(A C^{-1},BC^{-1})}=1.
$$
or equivalently the 2-cocycle condition is:
$$
\frac{\mu(A,B,1)}{\mu(AC^{-1}, BC^{-1},1)}
=\frac{\mu(A,C,1)}{\mu(B,C,1)}
\Leftrightarrow\frac{\omega(A,B)}{\omega(AC^{-1}, BC^{-1})}
=\frac{\omega(A,C)}{\omega(B,C)}.
$$

2. Extended double 2-cocycle condition: Mathematical structure behind?

Let us define a new object call $F$ which is related to the ordinary homogeneous group 2-cocycles $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ (also inhomogeneous group 2-cocycles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ ) with two tensor product inputs:
$$
F(A,B,\alpha ,\beta) :=\mu_1(A \otimes \alpha,B \otimes \beta,1)
=\omega_1(A \otimes \alpha,B \otimes \beta)
$$
also
$$
F(A,B,\alpha ,\beta) :=\mu_2(A \otimes B,\alpha \otimes \beta,1)=\omega_2(A \otimes B,\alpha \otimes \beta).
$$

The 2-cocycle condition for a homogeneous group 2-cocycle $\mu_1$ (also an inhomogeneous group 2-cocycle $\omega_1$ )
becomes:

$$
\frac{\omega_1(A \otimes \alpha,B \otimes \beta)}{\omega_1(AC^{-1} \otimes \alpha \gamma^{-1}, 
BC^{-1} \otimes \beta \gamma^{-1})}
=\frac{\omega_1(A \otimes \alpha,C \otimes \gamma)}{\omega_1(B \otimes \beta,C \otimes \gamma)}
$$

> $$\Rightarrow\boxed{
> \frac{F(A,B,\alpha ,\beta)}{
> F(AC^{-1},BC^{-1},\alpha\gamma^{-1} ,\beta \gamma^{-1})
> }
> =
> \frac{F(A,C,\alpha ,\gamma)}{
> F(B,C,\beta, \gamma)
> }}
> \tag{1}
> $$

The 2-cocycle condition for a homogeneous group 2-cocycle  $\mu_2$ (also an inhomogeneous group 2-cocycle $\omega_2$ )
becomes:

$$
\frac{\omega_2(A \otimes B, \alpha \otimes \beta)}{\omega_2(AC^{-1} \otimes B \gamma^{-1} , 
\alpha C^{-1} \otimes \beta \gamma^{-1})}
=\frac{\omega_2(A \otimes B,C \otimes \gamma)}{\omega_2(\alpha \otimes \beta,C \otimes \gamma)}
$$

> $$\Rightarrow\boxed{
> \frac{F(A,B,\alpha ,\beta)}{
> F(AC^{-1},B\gamma^{-1},\alpha C^{-1} ,\beta \gamma^{-1})
> }
> =
> \frac{F(A , B,C ,\gamma)}{
> F(\alpha , \beta,C ,\gamma)
> }} \tag{2}
> $$

Here all $A,B,C,\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in G$.

> **My puzzle for you**: Is there any known mathematical structures behind these two extended double 2-cocycle conditions in Eq.(1) and Eq.(2)? If so, what does the corresponding cocycle class solution form? Are there certain modified notions of cohomology group counting distinct classes of these cocycles $F(A,B,\alpha ,\beta)$?

(Thanks in advance for your answer.)